# how to format USB corrupted?

Tags: usb, format

I'm trying to format the usb I used to install Ubuntu. I tried, disk, gives error. With `fdisk` this is what I get:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   976773167   488386583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 7798 MB, 7798784000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 948 cylinders, total 15232000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x60dfafa1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           0     2156351     1078176    0  Empty
/dev/sdb2         2135488     2140031        2272   ef  EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb1'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb1: 1104 MB, 1104052224 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 134 cylinders, total 2156352 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x60dfafa1

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1p1   *           0     2156351     1078176    0  Empty
/dev/sdb1p2         2135488     2140031        2272   ef  EFI (FAT-12/16/32)

Disk /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt: 499.3 GB, 499310919680 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60704 cylinders, total 975216640 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 495.5 GB, 495456354304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60235 cylinders, total 967688192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 3841 MB, 3841982464 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 467 cylinders, total 7503872 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

And I don't know what to do...please help me! I am new to all this.

Comment: do you have gparted gui?

Comment: Don't use `fdisk`, use `parted`. Read `man parted`

Answer (score 2):

### Restore to a standard storage device

You can use mkusb to restore a cloned USB boot drive to a standard storage device with an MSDOS partition table and a FAT32 file system. I think this is what you mean by format.

See these links,

- [Install mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

  If you run standard Ubuntu live, you need an extra instruction to get the repository Universe. (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu have the repository Universe activated automatically.)

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
  ```
- [Use mkusb to restore to a standard storage device](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe)

  [image]

### Other partition table and/or file systems

If you need some other formatting, other partition table and or partitions with other file systems, you start with mkusb to remove data that might cause confusion, and use gparted afterwards.

- In this case it is enough to *let* **mkusb** *wipe the first mibibyte* and then
- Install **gparted** if not already installed

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install gparted
  ```
- And then use **gparted**

  - Start with the pull-down menu *Device - Create Partition Table* and then
  - *Create partitions with file systems* with the intuitive user interface.

### If still problems

if still problems, try according to this link, that might help you analyse the problem and find a solution.

- [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted - Analysis](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)